# Need Help Connecting Two VOIP Devices?

Tags: networking, virtualization, ip-address, voip

I have two Motorola XPR 8400 two way radio repeaters. These repeaters are capable of voice over ip. These two repeaters will be placed at two different sites with different ip addresses. I need to replicate this situation at the shop I work at, I can get them to run off of my network but I need a second IP address for the second repeater so that I know that they will work the way they are intended. What I am asking is it possible to create a second network for one of the repeaters through virtualization? and if so how would I go about doing this?

Comment: You can create a second network by connecting an Ethernet cable from one base station to a laptop and picking IP addresses for each out of thin air.

Comment: I will try that, I have little experience with voip.